# How to compactly write a block that executes a method with arguments

Tags: ruby

In the following code:

```
def main
  someArray.all? { |item| checkSomething(item) }
end

private
  def checkSomething(arg)
    ...
  end
```

How do I shorten the `all?` statement in order to ged rid of the redundant `item` variable?

I'm looking for something like `someArray.all?(checkSomething)` which gives a "wrong number of arguments" error.

Comment: Where is the `item` variable?

Comment: The OP, you can't do that with `#all?` .. as it doesn't take any parameter as argument.. You have to go with _block_ ..

Comment: You are actually calling `checkSomething` without any argument in `someArray.all?(checkSomething)`, that's why it complains.

Comment: Nope, there's no shorter way. The `to_proc` shortcut (for example, `ary.map(&:to_s)` ) does not apply here.

Comment: @limekin I know.. Block is a special argument..

Comment: @sawa Sorry, I fixed `i` to `item`.

Comment: @limekin I know why it complains - because in Ruby, `checkSomething` is a method call. That's why I'm looking for a different syntax. For example, in C# I would write `someArray.All(checkSomething)` (in C# this would work because `checkSomething` is not a method call unless you add `()`).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: `to_proc` works just fine in this case, see [Stefan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31245172/2988) for an example using `Method#to_proc`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yeah, that's a `to_proc` on a different object.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a slightly shorter code if `checkSomething` was a method on your object class. Don't know what it is, so, I'm guessing, you're working with primitives (numbers, strings, etc.). So something like this should work:

```
class Object
  def check_something
    # check self
  end
end

some_array.all?(&:check_something)
```

But this is, of course, a horrible, horrible way of going about it. Saving a few keystrokes at the cost of such global pollution - absolutely not worth it. Moreover, even this trick will not be available as soon as you will need to pass additional parameters to the check method.

Besides, the original code is quite readable too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-method) and [`Method#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) (i.e. `&method`) to get rid of the `item` variable, although it is slower:

```
def main(array)
  array.all?(&method(:check_something))
end

def check_something(arg)
  arg.odd?
end

main [1,3,5] #=> true
main [1,3,6] #=> false
```

Comment: It's not any shorter, is it? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It uses less variables ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but IIRC, using `method` is a non-negligible performance hit. It's up for the OP to decide what's more important :)

Answer (score 1):

If checkSomething is an item method (i.e. defined in the class of the 'i' object) you could do symbol to proc...

```
def main
  someArray.all?(&:checkSomething)
end
```

A method only has access to passed arguments, or to `self`so to bypass passing arguments you need to make the method an instance method of the object class (so it can use `self`)

The way you have it... where `checkSomething` is external to the `i` class... you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to keep your object's `checkSomething` private, I think this would be a good work around :

```
class Something
  def main
    someArray.all?(&checkSomething) 
  end

  private
    def checkSomething
      ->(item) do 
        # Checking part.
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For block that executes a method with arguments, Checkout this way...

```
def main
  someArray.all? &checkSomething(arg1, arg2, ...)
end

private
def checkSomething(arg1, arg2, ...)
  Proc.new { |item| ..... }
end
```

Answer (score -2):

could you not use a Ruby's collection method 'any?'  instead?

```
def main
  #students is an array of students
  students.any?(&:passed)
end

class Student
  def passed
    #code to check if student passed
  end
end
```

Ref http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F

Comment: `all?` and `any?` have the same constraint here... if you're using symbol-to-proc the method has to be a `Student` object method (as you did). Your answer would work with `all?` as well as `any?` so from that perspective there's no difference.

Comment: i did a little research on the difference between all? and any? there is a subtle difference...so yes depending on you requirement I agree you could use either